# Converter campo nvarchar(50) em datetime tabela SQLSRV

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, tsql

Preciso alterar um campo na tabela do banco de dados SQL cuja o formato está em `nvarchar(50)` e foi salvo valores no formato data `07/09/2017`, contendo valores `NULL` também! Preciso converter esse campo direto no banco de dados para `datetime` no formato `2017-07-09 00:00:00.000` via T-SQL?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: acredito que o banco não irá permitir conversão direta, você pode criar uma coluna temporária, fazer a conversão pra ela, apagar a coluna varchar e recria-la como datetime, e por fim, copiar os dados da coluna temporária para a nova coluna

Comment: talvez isso ajude, não entendo bem o inglês,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29776360/convert-varchar-column-to-datetime-in-sql-server

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-rename-transact-sql  uma etapa pode ser renomear a coluna temporaria para o nome original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crie uma nova coluna com o tipo novo, atualize-a com os valores convertidos, delete a coluna antiga, crie novamente como `DATETIME`, atualize-a com os valores da coluna nova e delete esta coluna auxiliar:

```
-- Cria a coluna auxiliar para recer um DATETIME
ALTER TABLE tb_processo ADD DataParcelaAntigaAUXILIAR DATETIME;
GO

-- Atualiza a coluna com o valor referente ao formato dd/MM/yyyy
UPDATE tp
   SET tp.DataParcelaAntigaAUXILIAR = CONVERT(datetime, tp.DataParcelaAntiga, 103)
  FROM tb_processos tp
 WHERE ISNULL(tp.DataParcelaAntiga, '') <> '';
GO

-- Elimina a coluna antiga
ALTER TABLE tb_processo DROP COLUMN DataParcelaAntiga;
GO

-- Recria a coluna antiga com o novo tipo
ALTER TABLE tb_processo ADD DataParcelaAntiga DATETIME;
GO

-- Atualiza o valor com base na coluna auxiliar
UPDATE tp
   SET tp.DataParcelaAntiga = tp.DataParcelaAntigaAUXILIAR
  FROM tb_processos tp
 WHERE ISNULL(tp.DataParcelaAntigaAUXILIAR, '') <> '';
GO

-- Elimina a coluna auxiliar
ALTER TABLE tb_processo DROP COLUMN DataParcelaAntigaAUXILIAR;
GO
```

---

A outra forma é criar a coluna auxiliar, converter os valores, apagar a antiga e renomear a auxiliar para ficar com o nome igual ao da antiga:

```
-- Cria a coluna auxiliar para recer um DATETIME
ALTER TABLE tb_processo ADD DataParcelaAntigaAUXILIAR DATETIME;
GO

-- Atualiza a coluna com o valor referente ao formato dd/MM/yyyy
UPDATE tp
   SET tp.DataParcelaAntigaAUXILIAR = CONVERT(datetime, tp.DataParcelaAntiga, 103)
  FROM tb_processos tp
 WHERE ISNULL(tp.DataParcelaAntiga, '') <> '';
GO

-- Elimina a coluna antiga
ALTER TABLE tb_processo DROP COLUMN DataParcelaAntiga;
GO

-- Renomeia a coluna "DataParcelaAntigaAUXILIAR" da tabela "tb_processo" para "DataParcelaAntiga".
EXEC SP_RENAME 'tb_processo.DataParcelaAntigaAUXILIAR', 'DataParcelaAntiga', 'COLUMN';
GO
```

---

> [**`SP_RENAME`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms188351(v=sql.120).aspx)
>
> Altera o nome de um objeto criado pelo usuário no banco de dados atual. Esse objeto pode ser uma tabela, índice, coluna, tipo de dados de alias ou tipo de dados `CLR` definido pelo usuário do `Microsoft .NET Framework Common Language Runtime`.

Comment: Fiz conforme o script, mas também obtiver um valor incorreto na conversão os campos com datas ficaram com uma data minima: 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000

Comment: @Evandro consegue colocar um exemplo de como está a data gravada?

Comment: adicionei uma imagem como esta a tabela no banco
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0YcT.jpg

Comment: @Evandro ajustei a solução para englobar os casos que estavam com a conversão incorreta. Verifique, por favor.

Comment: Obrigado a segunda conversão funcionou perfeitamente, bom trabalho.

Answer (score 1):

Obrigado pessoal, consegui fazer a conversão do campo nvarchar para datetime simplesmente da seguinte forma:

```
UPDATE tb_Processo SET DataParcelaAntiga = TRY_CAST(DataParcelaAntiga AS DATETIME)
```

Comment: Você mudou o tipo na sua tabela ?

Comment: Na realidade dessa forma você vai, provavelmente converter em um formato errado, principalmente porque será considerado o ano como primeira parte antes da `/` e por converter `VARCHAR` para `VARCHAR`

Comment: Verdade Sorack! obtive um valor invalido ao converter direto.

Answer (score 1):

Você precisar criar uma coluna nova para receber os seus dados convertidos e depois deletar a coluna antiga, após isso basta renomear a nova colunar.

Um detalhe importante no seu select é a filtragem dos dados, como você tem campos VAZIOS, isso pode gerar valores padrão na conversão.

Então você precisar filtra seus campos `NULL` e os `VAZIOS` para que sua conversão der certo sem as datas minima: `1900-01-01 00:00:00.000` o que causar isso são os seus campos VAZIOS, mas como não tem como converte um NULL para uma data vamos filtra-los também.

```
declare @tb_processos table
(
    id int,
    DataParcelaAntiga nvarchar(50)
)


insert into @tb_processos values
(1, '27/02/2017'),
(2, '28/02/2017'),
(3, ''),
(4, null)

select * , CONVERT(datetime, DataParcelaAntiga, 103) from @tb_processos
where DataParcelaAntiga is not null
and len(DataParcelaAntiga) > 0
```

Seu update ficaria assim.

```
UPDATE P
   SET P.DataAux = CONVERT(datetime, P.DataParcelaAntiga, 103)
   from tb_processos as P
   where P.DataParcelaAntiga is not null
and len(P.DataParcelaAntiga) > 0;
```